One part of the Kolmogorov three-series theorem
Let ${X_1,X_2,\dots}$ be a sequence of jointly independent real random variables, with the property that the series ${\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n}$ is almost surely convergent (i.e., the partial sums are almost surely convergent), and let ${A>0}$.
Show that ${\sum_{n=1}^\infty \hbox{Var}( X_n 1_{|X_n| \leq A} )}$ is finite.
We have reduced to the case where ${|X_n| \leq A}$ almost surely. If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \hbox{Var}(X_n)$ is infinite, using the Lindeberg CLT, one can show that ${\sum_{n=1}^N (X_n-{\bf E}X_n) / \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^N \hbox{Var}(X_n)}}$ converges in distribution to a standard normal distribution.
For clarity, let $\sigma_N^2 := \sum_{n=1}^N \hbox{Var}(X_n), T_N := \sum_{n=1}^N {\bf E}X_n, S_N := \sum_{n=1}^N X_n$. Hence $\displaystyle \frac{S_N - T_N}{\sigma_N}$ converges in distribution to $N(0,1)$. If $S$ is the putative almost sure limit of $S_N$, then in particular one has for the cdf:
$\displaystyle {\bf P}(\frac{S_N - T_N}{\sigma_N} \leq t) \geq {\bf P}(|S_N - S| < \varepsilon\ \text{and}\ \frac{S+\varepsilon-T_N}{\sigma_N} \leq t)$
for any $\varepsilon, t > 0$. Denote by $E$ and $F$ the events $|S_n - S| < \varepsilon$ and $\displaystyle \frac{S+\varepsilon-T_N}{\sigma_N} \leq t$ respectively. Then we see that RHS $= {\bf P}(E \wedge F) = {\bf P}(E) + {\bf P}(F) - {\bf P}(E \vee F)$, which converges to $1$, giving a contradiction. Is this a valid argument? (Specifically concerning the step of evauating $\displaystyle {\bf P}(\frac{S+\varepsilon-T_N}{\sigma_N} \leq t$)).

I just had a cursory read, but what is the reasoning behind the last inequality?

@Snoop: Thanks for the time. The event $(|S_N - S| < \varepsilon) \wedge (\frac{S+\varepsilon-T_N}{\sigma_N} \leq t)$ is contained in the event $\frac{S_N - T_N}{\sigma_N} \leq t$.

that would be the penultimate inequality

@Snoop: You are right. The original decomposition of probability was incorrect, argument is fixed correspondingly.
